# How to typeset an open circle with a dot inside, on an Internet forum?

Tags: symbols

I need to somehow put this symbol:

[http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/20/cauchy_cropped_cropped.png](http://wstaw.org/h/3aa0d48c610/)

And of course I mean this semi-open circle with a dot inside, right after "a_n".

I have seen it in a TeX document, this one: http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mmoszyns/Analiza-dla-informatykow-2014-15/analinf127.pdf (for example on page 48/49), where it is used to denote the Cauchy product.

I could not find neither this symbol nor a dotless open circle in The Comphehensive LaTeX symbol list (http:// www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

To make things even more awkward, I need to put it on an Internet forum. Due to that this idea `\odot \!\! \white{\bullet}` will not work: the background is not white, and even worse, it changes from post to post.

Thanks in advance for any idea how to do this.

EDIT: I *do not* want a normal, "closed" circle such as `\odot` or `\bigodot`, but an "open" one, as in the image above.
To be more specific: I want this: http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/22/ccccc.png and *not* this: http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/22/6718f3851aba6f5727da3da31bc74ee2.png

Also, since this is for an Internet forum, I can't `\def` anything.

Comment: the symbol is `\bigodot`, and it *is* in the comprehensive symbols list (p.25 in the lettersize version).  it's unicode `U+2A00`.  as for putting it on an internet forum, better to trust someone else.

Comment: the packages `latexsym`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`,
`txfonts`, `pxfonts`, and `wasysym` define`\odot` for that.

Comment: No and no. `\bigodot` and `\odot` both define a "normal", closed circle - and I want an open circle. See the attached picture.

Comment: On page 2 of the PDF, you find the authors email-address. Why not send him a friendly note and ask for it. Do you have some other reference for this symbol. Should that be part of the unicode? (can't find it there, though) The author writes "(raczej niespotykanym gdzie indziej...)/ *rather unusual elsewhere* ". Maybe you should search for a symbol, that your readers already know.

Comment: This guy is my lecturer... and the document is the script for my classes... And he didn't do the TeXing himself, but instead asked those people noted at the beginning of page 2 to do it, and their e-mail adress is not given there. I can find them through USOSweb, though.

Comment: Just as a curiosity, you might be interested to know that the same symbol was used in Renaissance music notation to indicate a type of meter with three notes per rhythmic group, "tempus imperfectum cum prolatione perfecta". There is a Unicode point for this, U+E914, available in the Bravura music font: see http://www.smufl.org/version/latest/range./medievalAndRenaissanceProlations/

Comment: @AndrewCashner U+E914 is in the Private Use Area, so it's not really a Unicode point.

Comment: thank you for the clarification and the specific reference.  i will pass this information on to the unicode technical committee.  (i hope someone there can read math in polish.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Actually, I am not certain if this symbol is not present only in this particular document... I don't know, maybe it is. But anyway, it quite obviously is not very commonly used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDITED to use `\clipbox` instead of white `\rule` overlay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,xcolor,trimclip}
\def\opendot{\mathbin{\clipbox{0pt 0pt .55ex 0pt}{$\odot$}}}
\begin{document}
$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n \opendot \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} b_n :=
  \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} c_n$
\end{document}
```

[image]

ADDENDUM:

Apparently, the web-based input available to the OP did not allow for the clipped solution.  However, I suggested (in the comments) something akin to `{{\textsf{C}\kern-.85ex\raisebox{.9pt}{$\cdot$}\kern .25ex}` which sufficed for the needs of the OP.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x\mathbin{\textsf{C}\kern-.85ex\raisebox{.9pt}{$\cdot$}\kern .25ex}y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this symbol is meant to be a binary operator acting on both sums, so `\mathbin` instead of `\mathop` might be "more" correct.

Comment: @HenriMenke  Thank you.  I was searching for the right match.

Comment: There's a problem... I need to put this on an Internet forum, so I'm not sure if I can define things... More, erasing things by overwriting them with anything white might look poorly, as the background *is not* white. See for example [this](http://www.matematyka.pl/335836,200.htm#p5295475) attempt.

Comment: @gaazkam  I couldn't say whether you are allowed to define things or not, but I have revised my solution to avoid a white box overlay.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm now sure, I can't `\def` anything. Typing `def`, even without the \, produces errors. OK, I guess I'll have to look past the colors; could you very kindly tell me how to put this right in the body? Typing `[tex]\mathbin{\clipbox{0pt 0pt .55ex 0pt}{\odot}}[/tex]` produces [this](http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/22/3f6a021abcad53c4ce9c90da12a998f4.png)... IIUC it seems that LaTeXing in the forum is like typing everything in the body section of the document, inside the $'s.

Comment: @gaazkam I am sorry that I do not have experience interfacing with web-based input.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes **I** am sorry for bothering you... But... how would you typeset this, if you were not to define anything, but just construct it each time in the body? Unless some special restrictions are set there, I *think* this would solve the problem.

Comment: @gaazkam  If I was really in a bind, perhaps `{\textsf{c}\kern-.7ex\raisebox{-.25pt}{$\cdot$}}`

Comment: @gaazkam If your question is about MathJax, then it's off topic here. With MathJax you can only use symbols that are in Unicode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Many thanks! You're a genius! It works! [Would be nice if it was larger, though.](http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/22/9fdd7e2101c7221c06e36a98ede765fa.png) I'm pretty embarassed to ask you if it could be possibly enlarged... But it's OK if it can't, it's just a forum after all.

Comment: @gaazkam  You could use a capital "C" instead of a lowercased "c".  As in `{\textsf{C}\kern-.85ex\raisebox{.9pt}{$\cdot$}\kern .25ex}`

Comment: @egreg It's not MathJax. IIUC on that forum they use a normal LaTeX engine to generate math and then convert it to a .png, which in turn is displayed in a post. However, they put some special restrictictions, as I noted above.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `{\textsf{C}\kern-.7ex\raisebox{.55pt}{$\cdot$}}` is the solution. [Works, and even looks nice!](http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/22/wreszcie.png) Many thanks again!

Comment: Oh, didn't notice your edited comment... your solution is even better, of course :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, once for the answer and once for the dialogue with the OP.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah, I also have that feeling :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution ([credit goes to a4karo from matematyka.pl](http://www.matematyka.pl/335836,200.htm#p5296030)):

`A \tikz{\draw (30:.3em) arc [start angle=30,end angle=330,radius=.3em]; \draw (0,0) circle (.1pt);} B=C`

[http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/23/9ff78e6d6784034c94d199ecb79ca1f7.png](http://wstaw.org/h/39369da73be/)

`[tex]A \tikz{\draw (45:.3em) arc [start angle=45,end angle=315,radius=.3em]; \fill (0,0) circle (.8pt);} B=C[/tex]`

[http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/23/dbf40b061d7af9e78eed82589e13d4cb.png](http://wstaw.org/h/5f6cb2e8b33/)

The parameters need to be manually adjusted depending on context, though:

[http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/23/7ae6b261cda0139def999a78900031cf.png](http://wstaw.org/h/a70ee3af1b0/)

[http://wstaw.org/m/2014/12/23/1ebab21212431359471f25a9b73d2107.png](http://wstaw.org/h/b812457f711/)

But I still think this is a worthy alternative.